# Circuitikz misplaces arrow of current label when using option 'auto'

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows, labels, circuitikz

The problem seems to result from the 'auto' option of tikzpicture. I have this problem as part of a bigger tikzpicture which mixes elements like blocks with circuitikz elements. Therefore the 'auto' option is handy, but somehow conflicts with circuitikz's labeling. So I have the following minimal example:

```
\documentclass[]{standalone}
\usepackage{circuitikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[auto]
    \draw (0,0) to[L, l=$L$, i=$i_L$] (3,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Which results in:
[image: Slightly misplaced arrow tip]

The tip of the arrow of the current label is not exactly on the line, but rather slightly above it. If the 'auto' option is not used, everything is fine.

I do not understand why this happens. Can someone explain this behavior? Is there a way to use 'auto' and circuitikz together?

Thanks

Comment: which version of `circuitikz` are you using? I am getting error with version: 0.8.3

Comment: @nidhin I'm using version 0.9.5. I updated from 0.9.4 since I thought that might play a role.

Comment: How about just switching off `auto` in that path? `\draw (0,0) to[L, l=$L$, i=$i_L$,auto=false] (3,0);`.

Comment: The arrow is also a node. I am not sure what `auto` is doing here... I will check when I can. At least I'll add a notice to the manual ;-)

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat Oh yes that works, especially if the problem occurs only a handful of times. However the accepted answer is more convenient, as there is no case where I want the auto option with currents.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat thanks --- I applied your suggestion on the main repository. So it will be fixed (swept under the carpet? ;-) maybe) with the next version, if no one says that the fix is wrong... https://github.com/circuitikz/circuitikz/issues/307    https://github.com/circuitikz/circuitikz/pull/308

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Disable `auto` for current arrow by setting:

```
\ctikzset{i/.append style={auto=false}}
```

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\ctikzset{i/.append style={auto=false}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[auto]
\draw (0,0) to[L, l=$L$, i=$i_L$] (3,0);   
\draw (0,-1) -- ++(4,0) node[midway]{\texttt{auto} works};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes, that's a convenient way to deal with it :) Actually, voltage arrows face the same problem which can be fixed this way too: `v/.append style={auto=false}`.

Comment: @quexor voltage arrows are also fixed with `i/.append style={auto=false}`.